# No module called found - why?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Still trying to get to grips with VSCode.

Trying to work through this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aIb6iQZkDw

I've run the first line of code:

from selenium import webdriver

The reply is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Tried the normal pip install method having thought I'd already installed it:

```
pip install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3[socks]~=1.26 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from selenium) (1.26.12)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2021.10.8 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from selenium) (2022.9.24)
Requirement already satisfied: trio~=0.17 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from selenium) (0.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: trio-websocket~=0.9 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from selenium) (0.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-generator>=1.9 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: outcome in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: exceptiongroup>=1.0.0rc9 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: wsproto>=0.14 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from trio-websocket~=0.9->selenium) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PySocks!=1.5.7,<2.0,>=1.5.6 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from urllib3[socks]~=1.26->selenium) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h11<1,>=0.9.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from wsproto>=0.14->trio-websocket~=0.9->selenium) (0.14.0)
```

What's going on?

Comment: Few questions, if you could answer - have you created a virtual environment? are you using a jupyter notebook to import selenium? is your notebook's kernel switched to the python interpretor of the new virtual environment? have you updated the kernelspec with this venv?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get to grips with VSCode and there is a jupyter notebook plugin. Not using virtual environment. Trying to just run code.

Comment: are you using a windows system or a mac/linux?

Comment: It looks like you already have selenium installed on your system. You may need to check your python path to make sure the selenium module is being recognized by your interpreter. You can do this by running the following command:

import sys
sys.path

Comment: Mac, I just want to add this comment

Comment: Mohamed Saeed.. Result is     
import sys sys.path
               ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
➜  Personal git:(main) ✗

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, the most possible reason is that you are in a wrong environment.

You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the correct interpreter if you are using python file.

If you are using jupyter notebook, click the icon in the upper right to choose python kernel.

[image]